# html5 canvas from external js file not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, external-js

Storing canvas js in external file is not working.

If the javascript that draws on the canvas is supplied in the html header, then the canvas draws the rectangle correctly.

Shown below is html that works (i.e. javascript in html header)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="javascript/text" src="js/nodeServer.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Canvas</h1>
    <canvas
      id="myCanvas"
      width="300"
      height="400"
      style="background-color:#efefef;"
    ></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

However, when I transfer the js to an external file located at js/main.js, the rectangle does not get drawn, but I think the reference is good. I don't know what is wrong.

Here is the html without the javascript in the header.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="javascript/text" src="js/nodeServer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Canvas</h1>
    <canvas
      id="myCanvas"
      width="300"
      height="400"
      style="background-color:#efefef;"
    ></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the main.js file

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
};
```

There are other relevant questions on stack, but the answers didn't solve my problem. What am I doing wrong? I was sure to put my js in a window.onload function, and I referenced the canvas script at the bottom of the body of the html.

Thanks for helping me.

... For more detailed information that may or may not be relevant, I am running the app with node. In the ubuntu terminal in the same directory as the html file,

```
node js/nodeServer.js
```

(You must have node installed to do this.)

Here are the contents of js/nodeServer.js file

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./index.html", function(err, html) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  http
    .createServer(function(request, response) {
      response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.write(html);
      response.end();
    })
    .listen(4242);
});
```

go to http://localhost:4242 in web browser like Chrome.

---

UPDATE: 
I noticed that when I open chrome developer tools and go to the 'sources' tab, that the js/main.js file contents are strangely showing my html code, not the js code. Below I'm giving the picture of the sources showing the index.html file and then a picture showing the main.js file. The html file does not have SyntaxError, but the main.js file is showing SyntaxError.

[image]

however, I double check to make sure that the main.js is javascript file on my os.

```
> cat js/main.js 

window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
};
```

Comment: It seems like the external path `js/main.js` is incorrect. Did you get any error in the browser console?

Comment: #randomSoul I have one error, but I don't know what it means. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    main.js:1"

Comment: You can copy paste the `error`. It is more likely showing `File not found`.

Comment: I can't find an error that says 'File not found'

Comment: Clue: I opened the chrome developer tools to look at the sources tab. Surprisingly, when I click on main.js file, it shows my html code! I copy-pasted the js into the main.js dev tools source file to replace the html it was showning, but it re-returns the same error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected tocken <" which I think means it isn't recognizing the js.

Comment: I'am not able to reproduce your issue. `when I click on main.js file, it shows my html code! `? No, it will show code from main.js file and not html code. Copy pasting in dev tools won't work.

Comment: I updated the post to include a picture of the devtool source of js/main.js file. You can see it is showing my html. Is this normal? I'm new to web dev, seems weird to me. This might be a result of me failing to configure the node server in the right way?

Comment: You have wrote `html code` in the `javascript file` (.js file). The `html` code should be `.html` file and the above `window.onload=..` should be in `.js` file. javascript don't understand the html and that is why it is showing the error.

Comment: I am not writing html code in my javascript file. I even showed the contents of the file from my computer using "cat js/main.js" - it is javascript code. Its the server or browser somehow not reading it correctly. I think this is a node server problem. I also showed my nodeServer.js code, maybe it is not right. I will make a separate question on Stack from perspective of node server configuration.

Comment: It is a node problem. If I run the app using 'xdg-open index.html' on ubuntu terminal, ignoring node server, then the canvas works. The source js file shows the true javascript code. Thank you for your help to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess since you are using a node server, you dont need to include the line `<script type="javascript/text" src="js/nodeServer.js"></script>` in your html.

Also you need to serve the .js file via your http server, you only are serving html in the code sample.

Try using something like express https://expressjs.com/ to handle serving files to your application.

If you dont need a node server you could do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-chaum-5c8dk

Comment: Yes, you are right, the app works the same without the reference to server js. I also see that I am only serving the html, but not the other files.  It looks like I should use express instead of http module, not in addition to http module. I will look into express now.